# If $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function then $|\phi(X)|\le|X|$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, recursion, ordinals

Using the Axiom of Choice we know that any set $X$ is equipotent to an unique initial ordinal $|X|$ that we call the cardinal of $X$, so we can organize the elements of $X$ in a transfinite succession, that is $X=\{x_0,...,x_n,...\}$, and so for any function $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ we can define the function

$$
\Phi:|X|\owns\alpha\rightarrow\phi(x_\alpha)\in Y
$$

therefore for any function $f$ we can define the ordinal $\mu_f=\min\{0\le\beta<|X|:\Phi(\beta)\notin f\}$ and so the operation

$$
\mathbf{G}(f):=\Phi(\mu_f)
$$

that through the transfinite recursion theorem allow to claim that there exist an operation $\mathbf{F}$ such that for any ordinal $\alpha$ it result that

$$
\mathbf{F}(\alpha)\equiv\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{F}|_\alpha)=\Phi(\mu_{\mathbf{F}|_\alpha})=\phi(x_{\mu_{\mathbf{F}|_\alpha}}).
$$

Well now through $\mathbf{F}$ and through the Axiom Schema of Comprehension we selected a set $Z=\{x_{\mu_{\mathbf{F}|_0}},...x_{\mu_{\mathbf{F}|_n}},...\}\subseteq X$ such that $\phi|_Z$ is injective and such that $\phi(Z)=\mathscr{ran}\phi:=\phi(X)$ and so  it result that $|\phi(X)|\le|X|$.

Is my prove correct? if not, how demonstrate the assertion? 
maybe the assertion is false?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: This seems (at best) unnecessarily convoluted to me. Given a well-ordering $(X,\le)$ (say, the one coming from a bijection with an ordinal), one can just define the function $g:\phi[X]\to X$, $g(x)=\min\{y\in X\,:\, \phi(y)=x\}$. Said function is injective, because $\phi\circ g=\operatorname{id}_{\phi[X]}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not understand the use of transfinite recursion in this case.

Once you have fixed a well-ordering on $X$ you are more or less done. For every $y\in\phi(X)$ simply define $\psi(y)$ to $x_\alpha$ with the minimum index such that $\phi(x_\alpha)=y$.

No recursion is needed. In fact, depending on how you formulate the axiom of choice, you might not even need to well-order $X$ at all. Simply note that for every $y\in\phi(X)$ the set $X_y=\{x\in X\mid\phi(x)=y\}$ is not empty, so there is a choice function, and since $X_y\cap X_{y'}=\varnothing$ if and only if $y\neq y'$, such a choice function is in fact injective.

In fact, in some situations one *states* the axiom of choice as "every surjection has an injective inverse", in which case you have to do exactly nothing to prove the claim.

---

In none of these cases we need to use transfinite recursion, though. Except if we want to somehow first prove that $X$ can be well-ordered *and then* use the well-ordering to define a choice function.